# Scaling amount of arguments/inputs for a function/method

Tags: java, c, matlab, function, methods

I am trying to write code to take the size, and vertices values of an adjacency matrix and find out things. My problem is not with finding out the things, but with writing a function/method that will take the right amount of inputs. I'd like to write this in MATLAB or Java (C would work too).

The  input will be given as: 
-The number of vertices n, followed by a comma
-The entries of the matrix in left to right, top to bottom format all separated by commas

So my question is: would there be a way to write a method or function in Java/MATLAB/C to take a scaling number of arguments? The number of arguments can be determined by the value of the first argument given if that helps.

I realize that taking it as an int array or String would be a lot simpler, but I must conform to the parameter specifications given. I would very much appreciate any advice and would have great admiration to anyone who can answer for all three languages.

Comment: MATLAB's `nargin` counts the number of inputs passed to a function. But this specification seems very odd. It would make more sense to pass the data as an array. What's the logic behind this specification?

Comment: yes, pass an array and check the size of array to enforce logic

Comment: This is a coding assignment given by one of my math professors. The specification seems a little vague, but I'd rather not risk an easy grade out of laziness. I have always been curious about this question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab it is absolutely possible. You can find a lot of examples [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html)(see example->Variable Number of Function Inputs) . Your arguments will be stored in a cell array `varargin`.